# How to run both systray application and outlook as a same user

Tags: c#, outlook

i have developed a systray application Which reads the every new mail received in outlook, process it and push to database. For my systray application to work, the outlook must up and running in the desktop. either he can start outlook before running the systray application or he can start outlook after running the systray application. The issue is the user may start the either application in different user(i.e, as administrator or user). At the time the systray application not able to connect the outlook. how can i able to connect outlook eventhough it started in different user

Comment: Why would your user need to be running either of them in elevated mode?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a tray app? Create a COM add-in - it will be running every time Outlook runs: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=36